# Rails strange parameter added on POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I realized recently that a parameter is added when I try to create multiple items of my class User in a POST request.

I have some permitted parametters:

```
def user_params
  params.permit(:account_id, users: [:type, :name, :account_id])
end
```

Here is my create method in my UsersController:

```
def create
  if user_params[:users].blank?
       render status: :no_content
       return
  end

  begin
    _users= User.create!(user_params[:users])
    render json: _users, status: :created
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    render json: _users.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

When I try to test this using Postman, I use these parameters:

```
{
    "users": [{
        "type": "test", 
        "name": "test", 
        "account_id": "2DAC41seuRwGIxTn4PQPZc"
    }, {
        "type": "test2", 
        "name": "test2", 
        "account_id": "2DAC41seuRwGIxTn4PQPZc"
    }]
}
```

Here is also the router conf:

```
resources :account, except: [:index] do
  resources :users, only: [:create, :show, :index]
end
```

Each time I do a POST request on `/accounts/2DAC41seuRwGIxTn4PQPZc/users`, I see in the rails console that the parameters are:

> Parameters: {"users"=>[{"type"=>"test", "name"=>"test",
> "account_id"=>"2DAC41seuRwGIxTn4PQPZc"}, {"type"=>"test2",
> "name"=>"test2", "account_id"=>"2DAC41seuRwGIxTn4PQPZc", }],
> "account_id"=>"2DAC41seuRwGIxTn4PQPZc", **"user"=>{}**}

> Unpermitted parameter: :user.

I don't know where this parameter come from. Can someone enlighten me ?

Note that I'm still learning rails and ruby overall, maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Are there any before_action methods or code on the users controller? My guess (not confident) Rails/gem is doing some magic and inserting the "user" in the params?

Comment: This certainly happens because the [ParamsWrapper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4.2/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html) does its thing and for the `create` endpoint the default would be to have everything nested below `:user` instead of `:users`.

Comment: Additionally to what @spickermann mentions, you declare a `users` via `resources` (plural), and that means that when you POST you create a single resource, hence it's adding the `user` as singular. I guess that you should just rename the parameters you permit in `user_params`, to make it more semantically correct.

Comment: @spickerman was right. Reading the ParamsWrapper documentation helped me understand the problem. I'm still not very comfortable with this singular/plural way of writing that seems typical of Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @spickerman mentioned it, the problem was that the ParamsWrapper was expecting a JSON format, and according to the [doc](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4.2/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html):

> If you enable ParamsWrapper for :json format, [...], it will be wrapped into a nested hash with the key name matching the controller's name.

However, even though the controller is plural, the model name has to be singular.

I fixed my problem changing `users` list to `user`:

```
{
    "user": [{
        "type": "test", 
        "name": "test", 
        "account_id": "2DAC41seuRwGIxTn4PQPZc"
    }, {
        "type": "test2", 
        "name": "test2", 
        "account_id": "2DAC41seuRwGIxTn4PQPZc"
    }]
}
```

> Parameters: {"user"=>[{"type"=>"test", "name"=>"test",
> "account_id"=>"2DAC41seuRwGIxTn4PQPZc"}, {"type"=>"test2",
> "name"=>"test2", "account_id"=>"2DAC41seuRwGIxTn4PQPZc", }],
> "account_id"=>"2DAC41seuRwGIxTn4PQPZc"}